# Dart assign a function/method to variable after declaration

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to assign a function, **with parameters**, to an **already declared** variable, So I be able to execute it later.

Something like that:

```
void main() {
  Function p;
  p = print('1'); // should not execute;
  p;
}
```

How do I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like

```dart
void main() {
  late Function p;
  p = () {
    print('1');
  };
  p(); // it will print 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For the example you have provided you can do this:

```
void main() {
  Function p = (){print('1');};
}
```

now you can call `p()` to execute it later.

Comment: Thanks Amir, but in my case I have to assign my function after the deceleration

Comment: @genericUser You’re welcome, nothing changes actually, you can do it this way: 
`void main() {
 late Function p;
  p = () {
    print('1');
  };
  p();
}`

Answer (score 0):

```
 void Function(Object? object) p;
 p = print; 
 p.call('1');
```

Comment: Hey @Raegtime thanks for replying, I have edited my question. I need to assign my the function after declaring the variable.

Comment: void Function(Object? object) p;
 p = ()=>print('1'); 
 p.call();